# Plot a part of data set

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot (with ggplot2) a part of table (2 column). for example from row1 to row100. How could I do it? Thanks a lot! 
I try with this but it does not work

```
ggplot(table) + geom_point(aes(x= Date[1:100], y = L [1:100]))

Date             L
01.01.2008 00:10      425

01.01.2008 00:20      425

01.01.2008 00:30      424

01.01.2008 00:40      425

01.01.2008 00:50      425

....
```

Answer (score 1):

Perform your subsetting outside of `aes()`.

```
ggplot(data = table[1:100,]) + geom_point(aes(x = Date, y = L))
```

Comment: there is some point which L is missing, how can i ignore it and show a note at that point? Thanks a lot!